# Почему блочный родитель inline-block-элемента имеет большую высоту, чем дочерний элемент

Tags: html, css, height, inline-block

Есть такая верстка:

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="childWrapper">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Стили

```
.parent {
  background-color: green;
}

.child {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Я ожидаю, что `childWrapper` будет высотой в 40px по его контенту, соответственно и `parent` тоже.
По факту есть зеленое пространство у `childWrapper`, он занимает 44px.
[image: лишние 4px]
Я попробовал убрать переносы строк и установить `childWrapper` свойство `line-height: 1.0`, но это не помогло.
Почему родитель больше по высоте, чем дочерний элемент? Возможно ли это поправить без установки высоты родителя?

Ссылка на планк: https://plnkr.co/edit/aQWL184bo53TWzti?preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому что пробелы и переводы строки имеют значение :) т.е. имеют размер

```
<div class="parent"> перевод строки->
пробелы ->    <div class="childWrapper"> перевод строки->
пробелы ->    <div class="child"></div> перевод строки->
  </div>
</div>
```

назчначьте родительскому блоку 0 размер шрифта и будет вам счастье (только не забудьте дочернему поставить что-то ненулевое)

```css
.parent {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 0;
}

.child {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="childWrapper">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Установка размера шрифта решает проблему, но получается, что можно было бы убрать пробелы и переводы строки, и это тоже должно работать. Но когда я убирал пробелы и переводы строк, написав весь body в одну строчку, проблема всё равно осталась.